# How to display data from Firebase Database to Vuetify Datatable with VueJs

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem on my code. I can't display my data to Vuetify Datatable, Although
it is enable Read and write on my Firebase Database:
Anyway here is my code for that, any wrong with my code? Comments were greatly appreciated:

```
<template v-for="user in users">
   <v-data-table
       v-bind:headers="headers"
       :items="user"
       hide-actions
       class="elevation-1"
        >
       <template slot="items" scope="props">
         <td>{{ users.title }}</td>
         <td class="text-xs-right">{{users.description }}</td>
       </template>
   </v-data-table>
</template>

import * as firebase from 'firebase'

let config = {
 //config here.....
}
let app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = app.database();
let userRef = db.ref('users');
export default{
    firebase:{
        users:userRef
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about firebase, but based on what I see, I would guess that none of your variables are defined. I think you need to define `headers` & `items `. Also, I don't know what the `scope="props"` bit is doing. That doesn't mean it's wrong, I just don't know what it's doing.

Comment: I'm assuming you have already been through this example : https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/firebase.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `data ()` function to return the object that is holding your data.

```
 export default {
   data () {
      return {
      // data for component here
      }
   }
 }
```

By iterating over the template you would be creating multiple data tables. The data table component itself handles iterating over the items.

The array of objects you pass in to the `:items` will be available through the `scope="props"`, the string assigned to `scope` can be named something besides props if you prefer. Your data will be in the `props.item` object. Also make sure your header array is defined somewhere.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
       v-bind:headers="headers"
       :items="exampleData" // pass the array of objects you want in the table here. 
       hide-actions
       class="elevation-1"
       >
       <template slot="items" scope="props">
         <td>{{ props.item.user}}</td>
         <td class="text-xs-right">{{props.item.title}}</td>
       </template>
   </v-data-table>
</template>

import * as firebase from 'firebase'

let config = {
 //config here.....
}
let app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = app.database();
let userRef = db.ref('users');
export default{
    data () {
      return {
        firebase:{
            users:userRef
        },
        exampleData: [
            {'user': 'Neo', 'title': 'CEO'},
            {'user': 'Trinity', 'title': 'CTO'}
        ],
        headers: [
            {text: 'User', value: 'user', align: 'left'},
            {text: 'Title', value: 'title', align: 'left'}
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 This had me puzzled for a while.   The website doesn't seem to document the fact that the data in `:items` is visible through `scope="props"`, and that individual items are visible through `props.item`.  It sort of just leaves you to figure it out through the examples.